# Transition is jerky when the element is slide up and down on mobile devices?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've created a modal that slides up and down on click using CSS and jQuery.

When viewed on the desktop, it looks "OK" ish but when viewed on mobile devices, its jerky. Especially when the modal goes down.

What I am tryingt o achieve is a very smooth slide up and down. I did come across quite a few similar questions but I don't see any difference between what I am doing and what was suggested to other people to fix this issue.

The main purpose of this modal is to be used in a hybrid mobile app in phonegap. And this modal should look similar to YouTube player on iPhones.... So if you open YouTube on your mobile device, and play a video, on the top left, you will see an arrow that's pointing down. If you click/tap on that, you will see that YouTube player will get minimise. That is the sort of animation that I am trying to achieve.

This is what I have so far:

https://jsfiddle.net/zshk3nex/1/

```js
$(document).on('click', '.tol', function() {

  if ($('.hid-box').hasClass("easout")) {
    $('.hid-box').removeClass("easout");
    $('.hid-box').addClass("easin");
    $('.hid-box').css('top', 0);

  } else {
    $('.hid-box').addClass("easin");
    $('.hid-box').css('top', 0);
  }
});


$(document).on('click', '.minifyBtn', function() {

  if ($('.hid-box').hasClass("easin")) {
    $('.hid-box').removeClass("easin");
    $('.hid-box').addClass("easout");
    $('.hid-box').css('top', '90%');

  } else {
    $('.hid-box').addClass("easout");
    $('.hid-box').css('top', '90%');
  }




});
```

```css
.holder {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9999;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
}

.hid-box {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #ff0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9999;
  top: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.easin {
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
}

.easout {
  transition: all 0.6s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="holder">
  <button class="tol">
  click here to show modal
  </button>

  <div class="hid-box">
    <div style="position:absolute;width:100%;height:100%;top:0;left:0;background:none;z-index:999;">
      <h1 class="minifyBtn">CSS3 slide up</h1>
      <p style="text-align:center;">
        <div style="text-align:center;" class="dsp player4" id="player4"></div>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Could someone please advice on this issue?

Comment: I've tested it here and everything goes ok. Which specific environment are you testing it? Tested on a Samsung Galaxy S7 phone.

Comment: @Christian, thanks for testing bud... I'm testing in iPhone 6s and when the modal goes down, its quite jittery and jerky.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolute properties such at `top` and `bottom` aren't great for animations. Instead you could use `transform`. `transform` performs far better in animations and transitions.

When using percentages in `transform` the percentage is based on the elements box, rather than the parent, like with almost all other css values.

Another thing that could help improve performs is to narrow down your `transition` property. In your case you have selected to transition `all` properties. You could set it to only transition the properties you need. In this case that would be `transition: transform 0.2s ease-in`. While this won't necessarily.

Let's clean up your code a little bit.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.tol', function() {
  $('.hid-box').toggleClass("active")
});
```

```css
.holder {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9999;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
}

.hid-box {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #ff0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9999;
  top: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: transform 200ms;
}

.hid-box.active {
  transform: translateY(-100%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="holder">
  <button class="tol">
  click here to show modal
  </button>

  <div class="hid-box">
    <div style="position:absolute;width:100%;height:100%;top:0;left:0;background:none;z-index:999;">
      <h1 class="minifyBtn">CSS3 slide up</h1>
      <p style="text-align:center;">
        <div style="text-align:center;" class="dsp player4" id="player4"></div>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've removed the vast majority of the jQuery you used, only toggling a single class now. I've moved the transition to the main element. I've also added a `active` class which simply sets the `transform` property to `translateY(-100%)`. This means it will move it `-100%` of the elements height.

All of this should make it perform better on mobile. However at the end of the day it will also depend on the strength of your device. If it is somewhat older it might not perform as well.

I hope that helps!

Comment: You seem to have put the toggle on the same button which hides behind the modal. so  it cannot be clicked on. also, I need to push the modal down for about 90%.. not 100% down so its invisible.

Comment: @Sparky, that is not what I am trying to achieve mate.

Comment: this is what I was trying to achieve: https://jsfiddle.net/zshk3nex/23/  I used the Mitchel's code and modified it slightly.. any cuggestion on the jQuery part to make it cleaner is welcomed.